# Access attribute names and add new attributes in processAlgorithm

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, python-script-tool

How can I access the layer attribute names of the selected layer?

I have tried checking on Google but all the methods are mostly for the previous version and I am using py3 version.

```
att = source.fields()
```

but it does not return any results. I am unable to find a suitable solution for the problem.

Comment: I meant to get all the attribute column names of the input vector layer

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
fieldnames = [f.name() for f in lyr.fields()]
print(fieldnames)

pv = lyr.dataProvider()
pv.addAttributes([QgsField('anewfield', QVariant.Int)])
lyr.updateFields()

fieldnames = [f.name() for f in lyr.fields()]
print(fieldnames)
```

[image]

Comment: I want to do it in python scripts inside processing toolbox

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the features of the input layer and add new features using QgsVectorLayer API.